# Is it correct to use "its" with a plural form

Tags: grammar

Is it correct to say :

> X company was founded in 2017. Its solutions aims to do stuff.

Intuitively I would have go for **theirs solutions aim** but the first one doesn't sound that bad to my hear while I feel like it's wrong to use **its** with a plural form.

Comment: Doesn't "It" correspond to the "X company" which is singular?

Comment: "X  company" is singular, so using "its" to refer to it makes perfect sense. Your problem is with "aims", which should be "aim", because it refers to the solutions, which is plural.

Comment: Ok, got it thanks ! :)

Comment: The possessive determiner (the pronoun used before a noun) is "their". "Theirs" is used when there's no noun (eg "the house is theirs").